# how to add id to the type select element of column filter in jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, datatable

```
    oTable.columnFilter({
       sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
       aoColumns: [                    
           { type: "select", values: myArray},                                    
           { type: "text" },
           { type: "select", values: category }                                            
       ]
    });
```

I want to bind data to one dropdown of a column filter, for that I need to assign ID or name to the dropdown ...How can I achieve this?
Here I'm using datatable version 1.9..

Comment: Need Best Solution ..Please  Suggest

Answer (score 0):

Use the property **createdRow** of datatable, The rowId is automatically created whenever there is any row created in the datatable. https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow for datatable 1.10+

http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html for datatable 1.9

```
  "createdRow": function (row, data, rowId) {
    var $rowCreated = $(row);
    $rowCreated.data('rowData', data).attr('data-row-id', rowId);

    //Row Single-Click Event Handler
    $rowCreated.on('click', function () {
      var $rowClicked = $(this);
      var rowData = $rowClicked.data('rowData');
      $rowClicked.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
      // Do any operation for onClick
    });
  },
```

For datatable 1.9

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
            //Here you have iDisplayIndex, the row index
        }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I'm asking not row id.I want to bind data to dropdown  of column filter dynamically for that i need to assign id for the dropdown  (type select).How can i assign ??